# Deriving the Hemholtz equation from the wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, wave-equation

I am trying to derive the Hemholtz equation in electromagnetism. In the Lorentz gauge $\partial_\mu A^\mu = 0$ the inhomogeneous maxwell equations read:
\begin{equation}\label{maxwell inh}
    \square A^\mu = \mu_0 J^\mu \iff \bigg(\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2\bigg)A^\mu = \mu_0 J^\mu
\end{equation}
Let us take a temporal Fourier transform:
\begin{align}
    A_\mu(\textbf{r},t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} \tilde{A}_\mu(\textbf{r},\omega) e^{-i\omega t}, \ J_\mu(\textbf{r},t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} \tilde{J}_\mu(\textbf{r},\omega) e^{-i\omega t}
\end{align}
and substitute into the wave equation:
\begin{align}
   &\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{d\omega}{2\pi} \bigg(\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2\bigg)\tilde{A}_\mu(\textbf{r},\omega) e^{-i\omega t} =\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} \mu_0 \tilde{J}_\mu(\textbf{r},\omega) e^{-i\omega t}\\
   &\implies \bigg(\nabla^2 + \frac{\omega^2}{c^2}\bigg)\tilde{A}_\mu = -\mu_0 \tilde{J}_\mu
\end{align}
The last equation is known as the Hemholtz equation. However, I'm not sure how to justify the last step since the integral over $\mathbb{R}$ of a non-zero quantity can still be zero i.e. an odd function.

Comment: Note you are just taking Fourier transform, which is invertible for e.g., treating $A(x,-),\tilde{A}(x,-)$ as distributions.

Comment: I don't see any problems. If both sides are zero the equation is satisfied trivially.